# Feature selection for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm classifying websites.  One of the tasks is to filter out porn.  I'm using is a binary SVM classifier with bag-of-words.  I have a question about the words I should include in BoW: should it be just porn-related words (words commonly found on porn websites) or should it also include words that are rarely found on porn websites, but found frequently on other websites as well (for example, "mathematics", "engineering", "guitar", "birth", etc)?.

The problem I'm encountering is false positives on medicine and family related sites.  If I only look for porn-related words, then the vectors for such sites end up very sparse.  Words like "sex" appear fairly often, but in a completely innocent context.

Should I include the non-porn words as well?  Or should I look at other ways of resolving the false positives?  Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: I think you should rely on frequencies of words calculated separately for entire corpus on documents (including "innocent" sites) and for the sites to be filtered out. You may look at [term frequency–inverse document frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). This approach is widely adopted by categorization services, and will allow you to minimize false positives because sporadic terms will not fire alarm until the number of **different** porn-related terms exceeds some threshold.

Answer (score 2):

another possible approach would be to make a **Language model** specifically for porn sites. I think, if you have n-grams (e.g. 3-grams) it should be easier to identify whether  particular word "sex" is related to porn, or other domain.

A theoretical guess: If you have a such language model, you wouldn't even need a classifier. (Perplexity, likelihood of the n-gram should be enough to decide ...)

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, but I've already committed to an SVM.  One of the reasons is it's a bit late to change the classifier now.  Another reason is I'm using features other than languages (such as the number of images, links, etc) and fitting them into a language model may be tricky.

Comment: @misha, that's pity. The more I'm thinking about the more it seems to me that better results should be given by an unsupervised learning (clustering), where you would create "porn" cluster and then try to identify whether a particular site is "far enough" from the cluster to be a porn site

Answer (score 2):

Topic modelling (try Latent Dirichlet Allocation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) would be able to handle this well.

Feeding the document topics as features to the classifier would help to avoid the problems you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You should include as many words as possible; ideally an entire dictionary. The classifier is able to identify websites by determining how similar they are to the classes you define. You need to give it the means to identify both classes, not just one of them. Think of being asked to identify cats in pictures, but only being shown cats to train. While for any particular picture you might be able to say that it doesn't look a lot like a cat (or rather any cat you've seen), you have no way of determining whether there's enough cat-ness for it still to be a cat.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'm not sure your cat analogy is valid, though.  To paraphrase, I'm showing the classifier pictures of cats, dogs, aeroplanes, etc.  However, the features I'm extracting at the moment are specific to cats: whiskers, ears, cuteness, purr volume, etc.  I could include features like number of engines, bark volume, etc -- but these should all be zero for a cat.    Won't they end up as "noise features" for the classifier?

Comment: For cats it would be noise, yes, but not for everything else. The idea is to use the features to make the life of the classifier easier. So if "bark volume" is greater than zero, the classifier would immediately be able to infer that it's not a cat.

Answer (score 1):

Include all of the words and let the SVM decide which are useful - the classifier needs to be able to distinguish between the positives and negatives, and negatives can also be characterized with words that are not in your target domain (porn), thus making the split between the examples potentially clearer.

Preferably, use not only single words, but also n-grams (e.g., 2 or 3-grams above a certain frequency) as additional features (this should help with your problem with medicine false positives). N-grams will also fit right in with your approach if you are using TF-IDF weighting.